# Why aren't the dragons spawning?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I go to the dragon locations in Skyrim, but there are no dragons.  I've looted the chest and learned the word, but there are no dragons to be seen.  I'm playing on a 360.

Comment: Have you got to the correct point of the main quest to unlock them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reach a certain point in the main questline.

> Upon the start of the quest "A Blade in the Dark", Alduin will begin to revive dragons from their burial mounds scattered across Skyrim.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Blade_in_the_Dark

Comment: Note that one the player completes [Dragon Rising](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising) (which is an earlier quest), *random* dragon spawns will start.

Comment: This is really interesting to know, I spotted a dragon flying high up in the skies once before this and tried chasing it to enter combat. Hadn't realized at the time they weren't officially in play yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish the 2nd **battle** in the main questline 'Dragons Rising' you need to do this to get your shouts this is the ONLY way to get dragons to start to spawn.

Look more on the www.elderscrollswiki.com